# Python: parse data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, urllib

I have a list of urls

```
yandex.ru/search?text=игрушка%20"веселая%20гусеница"%20keenway%20отзывы&lr=47
yandex.ru/search?text=модис&lr=47
yandex.ru/search?text=модис&lr=47
yandex.ru/search?text=авито&lr=47
yandex.ru/search?text=авито&lr=47
yandex.ru/search?text=цветок%20киддиленд%20музыкальный&lr=47
dns-shop.ru/product/c7bf1138670f3361/rul-hori-racing-wheel
dns-shop.ru/product/c7bf1138670f3361/rul-hori-racing-wheel#opinion
kaluga.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/ruli_dgoystiki_geympadi-c31/hori/reviews/rul_hori_racing_wheel_controller_ps_4_ps4_020e_acps440-274260.html
kazan.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/ruli_dgoystiki_geympadi-c31/hori/reviews/rul_hori_racing_wheel_controller_xboxone_xbox_005u_acxone34-274261.html
kazan.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/ruli_dgoystiki_geympadi-c31/hori/reviews/rul_hori_racing_wheel_controller_xboxone_xbox_005u_acxone34-274261.html
ebay.com
```

And I need to get text from tag `title` to every from this.

```
html = urllib.urlopen(url, proxies=proxies).read()
print html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
titles = soup.title.get_text()
```

When I print `html` I get real code of pages. But when I try print `title`
I get

```
ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved
```

for most of urls.

What's wrong there?

Comment: This has nothing to do with beautifulsoup. Your problem is retrieving the html not parsing it. I suggest you start by adding a header

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I add dictionary with proxies, but it doesn't work. Sometimes it returns instead `title` `Ой!`

Comment: So it works  sometimes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it works for some urls. For some url are blocked and proxy can't go through it, although I use a dictionary.